# Prefer provided library libc++_shared.so, instead of the version from NDK

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

I use `APP_STL := c++_shared` to build my Android application, and I would like to include a custom version of this library, and link against it and package it inside APK. But, regardless of what I do, Android Studio includes the version of `libc++_shared.so` from NDK. Among the logs it has

```
[arm64-v8a] "Prebuilt       ": "libc++_shared.so <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/"
```

I tried putting my version of the library in `jniLibs`, but it complains about duplicated libraries. When I add into my `build.gradle` file `packagingOptions`, it still prefers to package the NDK version into APK

```
  packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
  }
```

I tried to link against my version of the library inside `Android.mk`

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := my_c++_shared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_LIB_DIR)/libc++_shared.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It links against, it but then again packages the NDK version, and because of that the application crashes.

So how do I proceed to ignore NDK version? Setting `APP_STL := none` leads to no C++ standard library at all, even headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a missing feature in AGP. As far as I know there is no workaround. Subscribe/upvote https://issuetracker.google.com/214395989.

> I would like to include a custom version of this library

FWIW, you're well off into the weeds with this, and this could cause some painful compatibility issues with any third-party code (including androidx) that you need to use now or in the future. Not saying "don't do that", just a heads up.

Comment: Alright, but is there a way to know inside `Android.mk` if the library is already provided by NDK, so that I don't need to link against it by myself?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Say I use `pickFirst`, how would I know if the chosen library is among NDK's libraries, or my own provided

Comment: You can't afaik. The bug I linked is the FR to provide a useful API.